# Exibir uma DIV ao constatar que ela possui uma cor background

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

Preciso saber o como exibir uma DIV apenas se ela tiver uma cor BACKGROUND selecionada, caso ela não tenha, permaneça oculta. Pois tenho uma paleta de cores em CSS e quando eu selecionar uma cor, a DIV oculta fique visível.

Meu CSS:

```
.gerenciar-coluna-titulo{    
height:35px;
width:887px;      
float:left;
text-align:left;
line-height:55px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
color: #666666;
border-bottom: 0px double #ffffff;
text-indent:25px;
```

}

Comment: Consegue acessar o site https://jsfiddle.net/ e mostrar de forma mais sucinta oque você realmente pretende fazer? ou editar o post e reformular sua pergunta, da formo como está fica difícil entender oque você realmente quer fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Se utilizar jQuery é uma opção, podes fazê-lo da seguinte maneira:

```js
var containerDiv = $('.container');

if (containerDiv.css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 177, 0)') {
  $('.mostraDiv').show();
} else {
  $('.mostraDiv').hide();
}
```

```css
.container{ 
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 177, 0);
}
.mostraDiv {
    height:150px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:royalblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="mostraDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Tens aqui um exemplo no jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7jgxp4xs/.
Altera a cor do `background-color` da class `.container` no CSS de exemplo do jsFiddle, para poderes ver o código em ação.

Answer (score 0):

O CSS permite que você aplique um estilo quando uma classe específica existir, dessa forma seria possível mostrá-la. Assim:

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
section{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
}
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:green;
  font-size:200%;
  text-align:center;
  display:none;
}

div.active{display:block}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
  <div class="active">bin</div>
</section>
```

Agora sobre o atributo de uma div creio que não seja possível sem o uso de JS. Veja:

```js
function show(name){
  
  $('section div[name='+name+']').toggleClass('active');
  
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: green;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
div.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <button onclick="show('foo')">foo</button>
  <button onclick="show('bar')">bar</button>
  <button onclick="show('bin')">bin</button>
</nav>
<section>
  <div name="foo">foo</div>
  <div name="bar">bar</div>
  <div name="bin">bin</div>
</section>
```